# Checking error message in test in python2.7 and 3.4

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.4, python-unittest

I need to write a test using unittest that checks the content of an error message. This test needs to work for both python2.7 and python3.4. Originally, I had the test looking something like this:

```
class MyFuncTestCaes(TestCase)
    def test_my_func(self):
        with self.assertRaises(TypeError) as context:
            my_func()
        self.assertIn("some message", context.exception.message
```

This works for Python2.7, but not for Python3.4 - there no longer seems to be a `message` attribute on `exception`. How can I modify this test so that it works for both versions of Python?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. `assertRaisesRegexp` works in both Python2.7 and Python3.4, so I can do, making sure to escape whichever string I need checked:

```
class MyFuncTestCaes(TestCase)
    def test_my_func(self):
        with self.assertRaisesRegexp(TypeError, re.escape("some message")) as context:
            my_func()
```